# How do I get rid of “--” line separator when using grep

Tags: bash, macos, terminal, grep, bioinformatics

I'm using the commands given below for splitting my fastq file into two separate paired end reads files:

```
grep '@.*/1' -A 3 24538_7#2.fq >24538_7#2_1.fq
grep '@.*/2' -A 3 24538_7#2.fq >24538_7#2_2.fq
```

But it's automatically introducing a `--` line separator between the entries. Hence, making my fastq file inappropriate for further processing(because it then becomes an invalid fastq format).
So, I want to get rid of the line separator(`--`).
PS: I've found the answer for Linux machine but I'm using MacOS, and those didn't work on Mac terminal.

Comment: Welcome to SO Akhil, you have to mention 3 important things in your post, 1- sample input, 2- sample expected output with all your conditions and 3rd- your efforts to solve your problem(doesn't matter either correct or not as we all are here to learn),m cheers and happy learning.

Comment: If you do as Ravinder asked then we can show you the awk solution which will be brief, clear, simple, efficient and work portably on any UNIX box.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `--no-group-separator` option to suppress it (in GNU grep).

Alternatively, you could use (GNU) sed:

```
sed '\|@.*/1|,+3!d'
```

deletes all lines other than the one matching `@.*/1` and the next three lines.

For macOS sed, you could use

```
sed -n '\|@.*/1|{N;N;N;p;}'
```

but this gets unwieldy quickly for more context lines.

Comment: It's saying `sed: 1: "\|@.*/1|,+3!d": expected context address` and the new output file still includes the group separator

Comment: @AkhilVerma Hmm, I use GNU sed, macOS sed gives me that same message. Let me add a solution that works with macOS sed.

Comment: Yeah, it's working now. But integrating `sed` command with `grep` isn't working instead if I'll first generate a file from `grep` and then use `sed` on it, it works. Thanks :)

Comment: @AkhilVerma You should be able to use the sed command *instead* of the grep command, all the line filtering should happen in sed.

Comment: yes, it's working if I'll only use `sed`. Thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 1):

Another approach would be to chain grep with itself:

```
grep '@.*/1' -A 3 file.fq | grep -v "^--"
```

The second grep selects non-matching (`-v`) lines that start with `--` (though this pattern can sometimes be interpreted as a command line option, requiring some weird escaping like `"[-][-]"`, which is why i put the `^` there).